# Heroku CLI authentication issue

Tags: windows, heroku, heroku-cli

After a fresh install of Heroku on Windows 7, I can't seem to authenticate from the command-line.

Running the command: `heroku login` prompts me to enter my credentials. After doing so, I received an error:

```
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: my_email
Password: ************
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'z:/_netrc'
```

I am using PowerShell, and when I run the command `cat z:/_netrc`, I get this error:

```
cat : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'z' does not exist.
```

`Z:` is a network drive, and it is accessible from the file explorer.

I already have a `.netrc` file in my %HOME% path, but it does not contain the heroku login credentials.

Looking at the official documentation and CLI help, I couldn't find anything useful to fix this. How can I login to my heroku account?

```
> heroku version
heroku/7.16.6 win32-x64 node-v10.11.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, the issue is arising from not finding  `_netrc` file on your local computer that is required to complete login with Heroku. I have decided to create the file into following location of my windows 10 computer:

```
cmd>set HomeDrive=C:/Users/your Windows username/AppData/Local/heroku
```

In my case,

```
cmd>set HomeDrive=C:/Users/CrazyMoby/AppData/Local/heroku
```

Finally I ran `heroku login`

The above step resolved heroku login issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setx HOME <netrc_default_location>`

where `<netrc_default_location>` can be:

- <%NETRC%>\_netrc
- <%HOME%>\_netrc
- <%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%>\_netrc
- <%USERPROFILE%>\_netrc

Some clarification can be found [here](https://github.com/heroku/netrc) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication).

Probably it's your user <%USERPROFILE%>.

But if you don't need it, just remove _netrc file, reboot and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in powershell and the problem should be solved.

`$Env:HOMEDRIVE = "C:"`

If you need more information, check out the docs on windows environment variables.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

This way work for me. Write in PowerShell next code , where **"paulob"** need **change** to **your user**, because folser "_netrc" exist in:

```
$Env:HOMEDRIVE = "C:\Users\paulob\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from `GIT BASH` `cmd` instead of `PowerShell` if you can, I had the same problem and it worked in my case.